# Problems with vuex: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ctx.getProduct.image_url is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex, vue-router, vue-router4

I'm trying to load a product's data, passing props through the Vue Router, this is my code:

**...store/modules/products_manager.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/"

const state = {
    product: [],
    products: [],
    category: "",
}

const getters = {
    getProducts(state) {
        return state.products;
    },
    getProduct(state) {
        console.log("GET")
        console.log(state.product)
        return state.product;
    },
    getCategory(state) {
        return state.category;
    },
}

const actions = {
    getAllProducts({ commit }, payload) {
        const config = {
            params: {
                title: payload['name']
            }
        }
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios
            .get(`${BASE_URL}products/`, config)
            .then((response) => {
                commit("setProducts", response);
                resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    },
    getProductById({ commit }, payload) {
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios
            .get(`${BASE_URL}products/${payload}`)
            .then((response) => {
                commit("setProduct", response);
                console.log("PRODUCT")
                console.log(response.data)
                resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    },
    getCategoryById({ commit }, payload) {
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios
            .get(`${BASE_URL}categories/${payload}`)
            .then((response) => {
                commit("setCategory", response);
                resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    },
}

const mutations = {
    setProducts(state, data) {
        state.products = data.data;
    },
    setProduct(state, data) {
        console.log("SET")
        console.log(data.data)
        state.product = data.data;
    },
    setCategory(state, data) {
        state.category = data.data;
    },
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
}
```

**../components/ProductPage.vue**

```
<template lang="">
    <div>
        <p v-if="(getProduct != null || getProduct != undefined)" >{{ getProduct['image_url'][0] }}</p>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    name: 'Product',
    props: ["id", "category_id"],
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["getProduct", "getCategory"]),
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.id)
        console.log(this.category_id)
        this.$store.dispatch("getProductById", this.id)
        this.$store.dispatch("getCategoryById", this.category_id)
    }
}
</script>
```

But I'm having some problems, I'm starting with vuex and I'm not understanding many things yet.

[Error Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1OCx.png)

I did some tests, I used functions like created, updated, etc. With some of them, the information was even displayed on the screen, but it still generated the same errors. I believe it must be some error in the vue data flow, but I still don't understand how to solve it.

Sorry my bad english ;)

Solution:

```
<div>
    <p v-if="(getProduct['image_url'] != null || getProduct['image_url'] != undefined)" >{{ getProduct['image_url'][0] }}</p>
</div>
```

Thank's @yoduh

Comment: code in your template will run immediately when the component is created.  the error comes from the fact that `getProduct['image_url']` is not defined until after your async axios call is done fetching the data.  it still gets displayed because once the data does come in, the component rerenders successfully, but it's the first render that's causing the error.  you can prevent the error by modifying your `v-if` statement to make sure all of `getProduct['image_url']` is not undefined

Comment: @yoduh thank's man it's exactly what i wanted